# What Does filebuf::sync Do on an Input Buffer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, compiler-specific, filebuf

I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/filebuf/sync/) that, for an input buffer, `filebuf::sync`'s:

> effects -if any- depend on the library implementation

So my question then, is can anyone tell me what those effects are for gcc and Visual Studio?

Comment: @Downvoter Can I get some clarification on the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I think it's because the question isn't very clear... for example, do you know that `fflush` is a standard function?

Comment: @black  `class basic_filebuf` isn't even standard, but it's Microsoft's behind the scenes implementation of [`filebuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/filebuf/). (Incidentally gcc uses the same naming scheme.)

Comment: `basic_filebuf` _is_ standard.

Comment: @black Oh snap you are so right.

Answer (score 0):

GCC's internal implementation of `basic_filebuf` simply [aligns its `pbase()` and `pptr()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00882_source.html#l00895) with the comment:

> Make sure that the internal buffer resyncs its idea of file position with the external file.

Visual Studio's internal implementation of `basic_filebuf` calls `fflush(_Myfile)` which is not implemented in the header. So it's unclear what that call does. The call is commented with:

> synchronize C stream with external file

Comment: `basic_streambuf`? Do you mean `basic_` **file** `buf`?

Comment: @black Right again sir.